# Scroll viewport size at a time with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of divs on my page. Each div covers the full screen.
What I would like to do is- when user scroll up/down the page, it'll automatically scroll 955px (the viewport height) at a time.

[Here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) you can see an example.

Currently I have the following jquery code. But it scrolls to either top or bottom.

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function () {
    viewportHeight = $(window).height();
});

var previousScroll = 0;
var scrollCount = 1;


$(window).scroll(function () {     
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
        scrollCount++;
        var scrollAmount = scrollCount * viewportHeight;
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollAmount);
    } else {
        scrollCount--;
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollCount * viewportHeight);
    }
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

I'm not good at JQuery. Any help?

Comment: Provide a working example. With 1.6k reputation you must know that.

Comment: You are only scrolling the window though.. not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: so you're basically looking for paralllax?

Comment: @RachelGallen I don't know whether it's called paralllax.

Comment: @s.k.paul parallax is slightly different see the demo here https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/

Comment: @s.k.paul edited answer